# shift register(74hc595) and pic in ccs

Tags: microcontroller, pic, mplab, shift-register

When I write 8 bit in hc595 shift register, with i2c last bit go to Q0 in second hc595.

Why?

Schematic:

[image]

My code:

```
i2c_write(0b10101010);

latch_led_sensors_out();

delay_ms(200);
```

Comment: The 74HC595 is not an i2c device. It is normally connected as an SPI device. This has, I suspect, a lot to do with the problems you are encountering.

Comment: Could you please post your initialization of the I2C (or SPI?)

Comment: Just write manually bits to 74HC595.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the I2C protocol.  Even though you want to send out 8 bits, you are really sending out 9.  The way I2C works is the initial frame contains 7 (or 10) bits of address, plus one bit for read/write.  After those initial 8 bits are clocked out, the master sends an additional clock pulse to read in the ACK/NACK bit from the slave device.  Remember, the master controls the clock, even when the slave is driving the data pin.

Comment: this code:        data = 0x80;
                       spi_write(data);

Comment: you will be fine with SPI as SPI doesn't clock an ACK/NACK bit, just the data bits.

Comment: this code is on wrong, what? :    data1 = 0xBF;
spi_write(data1);

Comment: please send to me an example True like this: data1 = 0xBF;
    spi_write(data1);

Comment: sorry, I don't know what you are asking for.

Comment: What to write in brackets to receive the following information in the recipient